# Implementation of spreadsheet in Python?

Tags: python, spreadsheet

Does anyone know of any open-source implementations of spreadsheets in Python? What I am really after is providing the user with the ability to modify formulas used by my Python program using possibly complex spreadsheets. I am not looking for solutions to interact with spreadsheet applications like Excel.

EDIT: The software should preferably use a liberal open-source license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [pyspread](http://pyspread.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question, to make it specific that I am after a liberal license. If it does not exist, then this seems to be a good option.